# Gatsby Errors With Google Custom Search Engine Markup

Tags: javascript, gatsby

I'm new to Gatsby, and don't know how to get CSE to work.

```js
export default () => (
      <div class='col-md-4 the-search-box'>
        <span><gcse:searchbox-only></gcse:searchbox-only></span>
      </div>
)
```

I get the error:

> 22:16  error    'gcse' is not defined
>   react/jsx-no-undef

Any suggestions on how I can incorporate this into my page? Should I put it inside something else?

Thank you,
Evan Jerkunica

Comment: The error is thrown by es-lint. You could either disable that rule in the `eslint.rc` at the root directory, or only disable it in that file with an [inline comment](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments). For the namespace tag, JSX doesn't support it by default. Maybe this article will help you: https://itnext.io/using-react-for-xml-svg-470792625278

Comment: Thank you very much - I will give this a shot. But that link looks like exactly what I need ---- basically creating the equivalent of a:

<ImageImage>
  <ImageLoc>http://example.com/image.jpg</ImageLoc>
</ImageImage>

Comment: Yep, but don’t forget to turn off the eslint rule as well!

Comment: Roger that :) I don't know precisely what that means yet, but I will look at the other link you posted and try and figure it out.

Comment: By the way, how did you know that the error was thrown by es-lint? Was it because of the error 22:16 number?

Comment: The second line of the error, `react/jsx-no-undef`, is an eslint rule. I don't think you'd need to turn that one off actually (if you follow the instructions in the article), but when working with XML in React you might see more errors from eslint, for example it'll probably yell at you for using namespace in JSX

Comment: `const GcseSearchboxOnly = (p: *) => {
  const { children, ...props } = p;
  return React.createElement("cse:searchbox-only", props, children);
};

export default () => (
      <div class='col-md-4 the-search-box'>
        <span><gcse:searchbox-only></gcse:searchbox-only></span>
      </div>
)
`

Comment: So I substituted in my specific case into the code from that article. Since I didn't have nested elements, I figured I only needed 1 const declaration.

So I have this:

`const GcseSearchboxOnly = (p: *) => {
  const { children, ...props } = p;
  return React.createElement("gcse:searchbox-only", props, children);
};

export default () => (
      <div class='col-md-4 the-search-box'>
        <span><gcse:searchbox-only></gcse:searchbox-only></span>
      </div>
)
`
Unexpected token, expected "," (5:28)
> 5 | const GcseSearchboxOnly = (p: *) => {

Lmk if I can paypal you some $

Comment: haha sure, would you add more info of your current attempt and the new error message that you get to the question?

Comment: Ya so I got the error message on this line: `Unexpected token, expected "," (5:28) > 5 | const GcseSearchboxOnly = (p: *) => {`  --- the 28th character is the ":" character

Comment: and the code was `const GcseSearchboxOnly = (p: *) => { const { children, ...props } = p; return React.createElement("gcse:searchbox-only", props, children); }; export default () => ( <div class='col-md-4 the-search-box'> <span><gcse:searchbox-only></gcse:searchbox-only></span> </div> )`

Comment: are you using typescript?

Comment: I am not using typescript.

Comment: you should remove the `: *` part in `(p: *)` then, it's typescript syntax

Comment: Cool! I have to go to sleep right now, but I'll try it first thing tomorrow morning. Thank you for your help and I found your website and congrats on your child :)

Comment: New error now :)

`ERROR in ./src/pages/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/gatsby/dist/utils/babel-loader.js):
SyntaxError: C:\Users\dude\desktop\alpha-parasites.org\src\pages\index.js: Namespace tags are not supported by default. React's JSX doesn't support namespace tags. You can turn on the 'throwIfNamespace' flag to bypass this warning.
  10 | export default () => (
  11 |       <div class='col-md-4 the-search-box'>
> 12 |         <span><gcse:searchbox-only></gcse:searchbox-only></span>
     |                ^
  13 |       </div>
  14 | )
  15 |
`

Comment: So I think I need to set `"throwIfNamespace": false` --- any suggestions on where I put that? Is it in the babel presets file maybe? Or the plugin config file?

Comment: hey why don't you pm on [twitter](https://twitter.com/DerekNguyen10)? once I got a hold of the issue that you have here, I can help you edit the question & find an answer.

Comment: I can't figure out how to DM you on twitter. I haven't used twitter since 2010. You can email me at evan@probiotics.org I still plan to send some money your way once this is completed.